# Houdini - CSS Typed OM: How to get a value of a defined property through javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-houdini

**Usecase**

I have the custom property '**--animation-duration**' defined as an time value with the new '**registerProperty**' function:

```
CSS.registerProperty({
  name: '--animation-duration',
  syntax: '<time>',
  inherits: false,
  initialValue: '1s'
});
```

In my CSS, I can now add this property to my class and adjust it's value:

```
.my-el {
  --animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
```

Now I want to **get** the **value** of this property on my element trough javascript, **always in ms**. This can be achieved by the following line of code:

```
const duration = CSSNumericValue.parse(getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('--ripple-anim-duration')).to('ms').value; // 1500
```

---

**Question**

Is there a **shorter/better way** of getting this value in my general javascript?

---

**Extra**

I know you can do it shorter in a **worklet** (tested in the paint-worklet):

```
const duration = properties.get('--ripple-anim-duration').to('ms').value; // 1500
```

And that following code is not working in my general javascript:

```
const duration = el.attributeStyleMap.get('--ripple-anim-duration').to('ms').value; // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal way 
`el.computedStyleMap().get('--ripple-anim-duration').to('ms').value`

1. You don't need to use CSSNumericValue.parse
2. attributeStyleMap working for properties defined in style attribute

I've wrote a few posts about Custom Properties and Values, if you're interested:

- part 1: https://vitaliy-bobrov.github.io/blog/css-custom-properties-in-depth/
- part 2: https://vitaliy-bobrov.github.io/blog/css-custom-properties-in-depth-part-2/

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot!
Also: interesting blog posts, thanks for sharing.